# Error on querying Access link table in ASP page

Tags: mysql, ms-access, asp-classic

I am able to acccess the link tables from ms access database to My SQL. I am able to access through asp.net but through classic ASP i am getting the following error:

> Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005'
>   ODBC--connection to 'MYSQLDB' failed.

Comment: And your code looks like? And do you have the MySQL ODBC driver installed?

Comment: Either it has to be a server pc or your sql driver has to be installed in mixed mode